# MS Access Syntax error (missing operator)

Tags: ms-access

I am using the below code to get the record from a access database. Now i got the below error Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression.
I can't able to understand this issue. Please help me to fix this issue.

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"Select * from tbl_men_schedule where fld_mem_id=" + 0 + " and  fld_startdate=" + Convert.ToDateTime(txt_startDate.Text) + " and fld_enddate=" + Convert.ToDateTime(txt_enddate.Text) + "", con);
 da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 da.Fill(ds);

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'fld_mem_id=0 and  fld_startdate=1/4/2013 12:00:00 AM and fld_enddate=4/11/2013 12:00:00 AM'.
```

Comment: the error itself is self explanatory and suggest how you can fix.

Comment: looks like you forgot the quotes...

Comment: user2063626 I would like to fix my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `fld_startdate` and `fld_enddate` are Date/Time data type, enclose those date values with the `#` delimiter.

```sql
where
        fld_mem_id=0
    and fld_startdate=#1/4/2013 12:00:00 AM#
    and fld_enddate=#4/11/2013 12:00:00 AM#
```

If they are text data type, enclose them with quotes.

```sql
where
        fld_mem_id=0
    and fld_startdate='1/4/2013 12:00:00 AM'
    and fld_enddate='4/11/2013 12:00:00 AM'
```

However if you use a parameter query instead, you wouldn't need to delimit those values.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement should be -

```
"Select * from tbl_men_schedule where fld_mem_id=" + 0 + " and  fld_startdate='" + Convert.ToDateTime(txt_startDate.Text) + "' and fld_enddate='" + Convert.ToDateTime(txt_enddate.Text) + "'"
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

If you hardcoding "0"... and you're missing single quotes.

```
"Select * from tbl_men_schedule where fld_mem_id=0 and fld_startdate='" + 
txt_startDate.Text + "' and fld_enddate='" + 
txt_enddate.Text + "'"
```